# OPENDATASOURCE Alternatives

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I need to load several Excel files into the database (SQL Server 2008 r2) on an ongoing basis via SSIS.  The problem I am facing is that some of the files require manipulation such as some of the header rows vary with how many actual header rows there are each month (sometimes there may be 15 sometimes there may be 17) and the sheetname is not consistent from month to month.
Also on occassion some of the files have other data source connections in them so the occassional message box will pop asking if I want to refresh the data or enable the content.

Since MS Office is a client side app and is not really meant to be running automated in the background I need a way to load this data on our server through our scheduler (an SSIS package running in 64-bit mode that kicks off other SSIS packages).

I found a way to pull the sheetnames from an Excel file without having to have MS Office on the server (so that eliminates one issue).  I found the OPENROWSET and OPENDATASOURCE commands which work beautifully...when ad hoc queries are allowed.   The problem is that due to security standards ad hoc queries are not allowed.

What alternatives are there that will allow me to load the Excel file in an automated fashion but will not require ad hoc queries to be enabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A linked server may work for you, you will need a seperate linked server for each excel file, you can do it dinamic with [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, that would cause there to be hundreds of linked servers after a couple of weeks.  And our account doesn't have permission to create/drop them on the fly so that's not going to work for us. :(